# Meteor Subscribe doesn't update sort order of collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

```
// Snippet from Template
<div class="post-container">
  {{#each elements}}
    {{> post-element this}}
  {{/each}}
</div>

// Snippet from Client 
Meteor.subscribe('thePosts');

// Snippet from Server
Meteor.publish('thePosts', function(){
  return Posts.find({},  {sort:{createdAt:-1}, reactive:true});
});
```

When I do...

```
Posts.insert({body:postBody, createdAt: new Date()});
```

The post document gets added and appears at the end of my list, as opposed to descending order as specified in my publish function.  Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The publish function determines which records should be synced to the mini-mongo database of any subscribing clients. So sorting the data in the publish function actually has no effect on the client, as the client-side database will likely store them in some other way.

Of course you may want to use sort in a publisher's `find` in order to limit the number of records to the N most recent - but again this is just a way of deciding which records get synced and not how they are to be stored/used by the client.

Once the records have been synced to the client, it is up to the template code to determine how the results should be displayed. For example:

```
Template.myTemplate.elements = function() {
  return Posts.find({}, {sort: {createdAt:-1}});
}
```

Also see the "sorted publish" section of my post on [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Comment: David, this is really the question I was looking to have answered!  Excellent answer, thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You just saved me tons of time :-)

Comment: These days, one of my favorite type of moments on SO is to have a meteor question, find the David Weldon answer to it, and smile while up-voting it. Cheers David (& ty)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't posted your template helper code.

When you do `return Posts.find()` from the helper function, the query should also contain the sort arguments, like as below:

```
Template.myTemplate.elements = function(){
   Meteor.subscribe('thePosts');
   return Posts.find({},  {sort:{createdAt:-1}, reactive:true});
}
```

Comment: Template functions run in a reactive context so the `reactive:true` is not needed.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was defaulted to true, I was just messing around with different solutions.

Comment: sohel, you were correct the helper function should be doing filtering.  The publish pushes syncs document to browser. I now understand what's going on here thanks guys!

Comment: how about if you want to sort based on geo-location? it's as if that field is not exposed by MongoDB.

Comment: When you sort large amount of data on client side, it hangs the browser