# meteor publish with limit and sort

Tags: meteor

I have the following publication:

```
Meteor.publish('times', function() {
    return Times.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}, {limit: 5});
})
```

This returns all records, limit is ignored. However this

```
Meteor.publish('times', function() {
    return Times.find({}, {limit: 5});
})
```

returns 5 records, but in the wrong order. How do I limit and sort in a publication?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See the example in the [forEach](http://docs.meteor.com/#foreach) section of the docs, and the documentation for [find](http://docs.meteor.com/#find). `limit` is a key of the `options` object, so it should be:

```js
Times.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, limit: 5});
```

Note that if you want the documents in sorted order on the client, you will need to [sort them again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153349/meteor-subscribe-doesnt-update-sort-order-of-collection) in your template code.