# Meteor Publish & Subscribe Not returning results using selector

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I have the following code:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Items } from './collection';

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      Meteor.publish('items', function(options, owner) {

        let selector = {
          $and: [{ ownerId: owner}]
        }

        return Items.find(selector, options);

      });
    }
```

And on the client side I have:

```
this.subscribe('items', () => [{
      limit: this.getReactively('querylimit'),
      sort: {dateTime: -1}
    },
    this.getReactively('ownerId')
    ]);
```

The above does not return any results. However, when I change the return statement to the following, it works!

```
return Items.find({ ownerId: '7QcWm55wGw69hpuy2' }, options); //works !!!
```

I'm not very familiar with Mongo/Meteor query selectors. Passing the query as a variable to Items.find() seems to be messing something up. Can someone please help me figure this out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass a function as the selector, which won't work. Functions can't be serialized and sent from the client to the server. Instead you need to evaluate the `options` and the `owner` separately. Here's an example:

```js
var owner = this.getReactively('ownerId');
var options = {
  limit: this.getReactively('querylimit'),
  sort: {dateTime: -1}
};

this.subscribe('items', options, owner);
```

Note that the published documents will not [arrive in sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153349/meteor-subscribe-doesnt-update-sort-order-of-collection), so unless you are using a `limit`, the `sort` doesn't help here.

Also note that if you need the subscription to rerun after the owner or query limit change, you'll need to subscribe inside of an [autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun).

Here's a start on an improved implementation:

```js
Meteor.publish('items', function(options, owner) {
  // DANGER! Actually check this against something safe!
  check(options, Object);

  // DANGER! Should any user subscribe for any owner's items?
  check(owner, Match.Maybe(String));

  // Publish the current user's items by default.
  if (!owner) {
    owner = this.userId;
  }

  return Items.find({ ownerId: owner }, options);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm on mobile at the moment so I can't check for now. However, I wonder why I was able to use console.log on server side to print the arguments. console.log(selector) prints the ownerId string that I've pasted in the second return statement.

Comment: Thanks again, however this does't seem to solve the issue

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log` the arguments to the `publish` function? Did you put the `subscribe` in an `autorun`?

Comment: Oops! Forgive me, my bad. While changing everything I had code moved out from the callback function of the subscription. It works as expected now! Thanks a lot for your help!